# Flask-Sqlite posting to DB from webform

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, webforms

I have started just learning Flask and tried to find an answer how to post to SQLite DB from webform. So far haven't managed to get it work and bit lost with this. I manage to print values from DB based on code sample from simplypython but don't know how to add new ones from webform.

I would need to be able to address elements, open connection to the database, Insert values, save and close the connection. As far as I am aware I should add the POST method to the app.py and use request.form statement to pull the elements when submit button is pressed.

then the code should automatically display all the values on index html, which already works. could you please help me with the code I need to add to app.py file to get values added to DB and what to add to form action webform-section on html file?

---

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask Intro</title>
<!--  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  -->
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">


      <h3  potsit </h3>
     {% for post in posts %}
     Titleotsikko: {{post.title }} <br>
     Postotsikko: {{post.description}} 

     {% endfor %}

    </div>

<div>

<form action="/????????????NOT SURE WHERE  TO DIRECT" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="title">title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="description">description:</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" />
    </div>


    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Add to db</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

---

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, g
import sqlite3


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')

def home():
      g.db = sqlite3.connect("sample.db")
      cur = g.db.execute('select * from posts')
      posts = [dict(title=row[0], description=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
      g.db.close()
      return render_template("index.html", posts=posts)



if __name__=='__main__':
 app.run(debug=True)
```

---

### sql.py

```
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect("sample.db") as connection:
  c = connection.cursor()
  c.execute("DROP TABLE posts")  
  c.execute("CREATE TABLE posts(title TEXT, description TEXT)")
  c.execute('INSERT INTO posts VALUES("Luck", "no luck.")')
```

EDIT

I made some changes based on the suggestion from Paul Rooney and created file called post.html, moved the form there from index.htmland added another @route on the app.py file. I believe I'm not far off but after trying to figure this out since Tuesday hoping to get it work. Unfortunately now I receive an error 405 'The method is not allowed for the requested URL.' and I'm stuck with this after trying different options.

---

### post.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask post</title>
<!--  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  -->
  </head>
  <body

<div>

<form action="/post" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="title">title:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="description">description:</label>
        <input type="text" id="description" />
    </div>


    <div class="button">
        <button type="submit">Add to db</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

---

### (edited)   app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, g, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
     g.db = sqlite3.connect("sample.db")
     cur = g.db.execute('select * from posts')
     posts = [dict(title=row[0], description=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]

     g.db.close()
     return render_template("index.html", posts=posts)


    @app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
    def post():
        title=request.form['title']
        description=request.form['description']
        print title, description
        return redirect(url_for('/'))

    if __name__=='__main__':
      app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Add another route (for example call it `/post`) to app.py, which handles the post method (see [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#http-methods)). Then the action in your form would simply be `'/post'`. After you've inserted the data in the DB simply redirect the client back to `/` and it should display with the updated values. You could look at using `Flask-WTF` to handle the html form in a nicer way.

Comment: Thanks. I will certainly try Flask-WTF in the future. Unfortunately now I receive  an error 405 'The method is not allowed for the requested URL.'  Edited the changes to my OP

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question you should pick an endpoint to post your data to and use that in both your flask app and the html form action.

I suggested `post` in comments but it could be anything. I think you've grasped what to do here but for completeness.

**The HTML**

```
<form action="/post" method="post">
```

**The Python Code**

Add a route to handle the POSTed data.

```
@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    # Do db stuff then redirect back to index page.
    pass
```

**Edited Question**

You have an indentation error in your code, which is causing the 405 error. Your `post` function is inside your `home` function. Make it more like this

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, g, redirect, url_for
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
     g.db = sqlite3.connect("sample.db")
     cur = g.db.execute('select * from posts')
     posts = [dict(title=row[0], description=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]

     g.db.close()
     return render_template("index.html", posts=posts)

# One level of indentation removed from here downwards
@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    title=request.form['title']
    description=request.form['description']
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

if __name__=='__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

After that I see a `400 Bad Request` error, which stems from the fact that you don't have `name` parameters in your html form.

The attempt to access the `title` and `description` values in the `form` dict in app.py will throw a `KeyError` exception, as those keys will not be present without the `name` parameter in the html.

If you add them e.g.

```
...
<input type="text" id="title" name='title'/>
...
<input type="text" id="description" name='description'/>
...
```

Then it will run all the way through your function.

The next issue will be

```
redirect(url_for('/'))
```

instead use

```
redirect(url_for('home'))
```

`home` being the name of the function called for path '/'.

After that you should be good to go.

Comment: I still keep on getting the 405 error.  "Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

Comment: I added all the text you suggested. In addition of the files I have mentioned I have one more file in project called 'sample.db' (in same directory as app.py )containing only one line as follows : 'SQLite format 3'   . Does that look ok and what could cause 405-error? Should I have GET method somehow added to my /post route on app.py -file?

Comment: Its an indentation error in your code. Your `post` route is defined inside your `main` route. De-indent the `post` function.

Comment: The `sample.db` file is just your sqlite database. It is supposed to be there and shouldn't interfere with flask.

Comment: I still get the 405 error and now accessing index page gives me an error: sqlite3.DatabaseError,DatabaseError: file is encrypted or is not a database. When I tried to run the same code on my raspberry pi I got the 404 error but the index page was working fine. Could these issues have something to do with different sqlite, python, flask -versions? Also did you have a look at the code or did you actually tried to run as it is? If I know the answer I can troubleshoot better. btw .I am not running flask on virtualenv. I have done some stuff with python, js and html, CSS and never had many problems

Comment: Sounds like your db is corrupted. Delete it and run your `sql.py` again. You'll probably need to comment out the line that does the drop. As for the 405 check over your code again and ensure it indented correctly and you are using the right action in your html. I can run it with no issues.

Comment: Didn't get it to work for ages. Like you said there was some kind of an corruption issue with DB. Can't explain what I did exactly but it worked.